# Don't sort number in SpGridView

Tags: 2010, web-part, spgridview

I have a SpGridView whit BoundFiled. I set a ObjectDataSource for it.

```
        sourceDataTable = new DataTable ();
        myDataTable = new DataTableWrapper(sourceDataTable);
        Type t = myDataTable.GetType();

        ObjectDataSource ds = new ObjectDataSource();
        ds.TypeName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName;
        ds.EnableViewState = false;
        ds.ID = "myDataSource";
        ds.SelectMethod = "GetTable";
        ds.ObjectCreating += new ObjectDataSourceObjectEventHandler(ds_ObjectCreating);
       this.Controls.Add(ds);
```

I created a DataTable with 3 columns. I fill it with name,number. and set for sourceDataTable.

When i sort SpGridView, name  column sorting but number column don't sort.

I convert Number to string but don't sort.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to troubleshoot since you didn't post all the code...

I would make sure your BoundField is setup correctly and the SortExpresssion property is being set to the correct column in your DataTable:

```
BoundField column = new BoundField();
column.DataField = name;
column.SortExpression = name;
column.HeaderText = name;
```

If that doesn't work, read Erik's wonderful blog post: [Building A SPGridView Control – Part 1: Introducing the SPGridView](http://www.reversealchemy.net/blog/2009/05/01/building-a-spgridview-control-part-1-introducing-the-spgridview/).

Comment: I use this code and set sortexpression for all column, but don't work.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? Or, can you post the rest of our code?

Comment: Yes, i use this link.